# Date field creation in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework Code First method to create my database table. The following code creates a DATETIME column in the database, but I want to create a DATE column.

```
//[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }


        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
```

The Column Attribute is not working.How can I create a column of type DATE, during table creation?

Thanks!

Comment: Uncomment the attribute  [Column(TypeName = "Date")]

Comment: I commented it because it does not work.

Comment: Then still uncomment it so it's clear for people that you're including it and yet doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can map your entities to your tables in the DbContext in the OnModelCreating method. Personally I prefer to create a mapping class per entity and reference it within this method. Example:

EDIT - Updated Code. This is fully functional code.

```
public sealed class MyDb : DbContext
{
    static MyDb()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDb>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDb>());
    }
    public MyDb(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyMapper());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<TesTme> Items { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<TesTme>
{
    public MyMapper()
    {
        // other mapping info
        this.ToTable("TestTable");
        HasKey(x => x.MyId);
        this.Property(x => x.MyId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.dt).HasColumnType("date");
    }
}
public sealed class TesTme
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }

}

public sealed class SomeCallerOfTheDbContext
{
    public void TestMe()
    {
        // this is the entry point
        using (var context = new MyDb("connectionStringName"))
        {
            var items = context.Items.ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @smriti - It does work, I tested the code before I posted but I will update it so it is a complete self contained example.

Comment: @smriti Try it again. The original code was meant to show you what to do, it was not meant to be run as is. This is an updated example that can run on its own as long as you supply correct credentials in a connection string located in the app.config or web.config or pass in a hard coded connection string.

Comment: DateTime TseTme.dt cannot implicitly convert datetime to System.Timespan?

Comment: @smriti - that error sounds like you are doing something wrong in the calling code. The sample above answers your original question/problem. Your calling code is probably trying to cast the datetime to a timespan. I can't comment on that because you would need to post that code so we know where the error is occurring.

Comment: @smriti - if you find my answer is helpful please mark it as 'Answer' or if you have additional questions please post them.